# Flutter: When I run this code flutter build appbundle this error occurs

Tags: flutter, release, app-bundle

PS C:\Users\saikr\projects\Todo-Flutter-master> flutter build appbundle

Building with sound null safety

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 36KB to 28KB: Removed 21%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:signingConfigWriterRelease' (type 'SigningConfigWriterTask').

> No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyPassword'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             95.7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Anyone know how to solve this error? if so do let me know

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new sign key, I think your sign key is broken

Comment: Okay will try and let you know

Comment: Building with sound null safety 

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 36KB to 28KB: Removed 21%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:signingConfigWriterRelease' (type 'SigningConfigWriterTask').
> No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyPassword'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
It shows the same error again

Comment: its look like your entering a work password check that too

Comment: you might make a mistake between two passwords that it needs to sign your project

Comment: The store password and the key password are the same in my case